# Vintage Car Models

Tags: cars, engine, vintage

I've been looking for a recording of a '68 Plymouth Barracuda or something close that has a v80 engine, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Have any of you guys recorded this car and are willing to share? I need the start of the engine, and an idling and driving of the car while it's on for the scene. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recorded a V8 Cuda years ago for a film, will have a look

Comment: I have a bunch of onboard recordings (exhaust mic + engine mic) and some exterior start/away/passbys etc... recorded back in 2001 so 16bit 44.1k on a Tascam DAP1 DAT recorder... 

Comment: ps what do u mean by 'idling' of the car when driving? either its idling & stationary, or its driving (med? slow? fast? accelerating? decelerating?) 

Comment: try these:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/transfer/cudaV8.zip

Comment: Ah, the venerable DAP1. I did a lot of recording with one of those over the last 15 years...

Comment: Thanks Tim! These shall work. I meant to put an "idling and driving of the car."
BTW can't wait to hear the tortured piano library man.

Comment: Isn't Social Sound Design the best?